# How can I create a macOS .app bundle for a SFML game?

Tags: c++, macos, sfml, app-bundle

I'm on macOS and I'm compiling my game with

```
g++ -F Frameworks -rpath Frameworks {{frameworks}} src/main.cpp -o game
```

I was following instructions on [apple developer documents](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/CoreFoundation/Conceptual/CFBundles/BundleTypes/BundleTypes.html)
about how to create a macOS .app bundle, I have the correct folder structures and files but I still can't launch the app.

I got the error message:

`Dyld Error Message:
  Library not loaded: @rpath/sfml-window.framework/Versions/2.5.1/sfml-window
  Referenced from: /Users/USER/*/test.app/Contents/MacOS/game
  Reason: image not found`

All of my framework bundles are in `test.app/Contents/Frameworks` and I'm able to run the binary in the Contents folder by `./MacOS/game`. However it works if I just use the absolute path of the framework directory.

What should I pass as my `-rpath` argument?

Comment: Without seeing what error messages are displayed, we can't tell you what's wrong. Open up Console.app, then launch your app, then see what errors are displayed and edit them into your question above by pressing the "edit" button.

Comment: @user1118321 Thank you for the reply, I now got the error messages and edited the question!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [this link](https://wincent.com/wiki/@executable_path,_@load_path_and_@rpath), you need to have your `rpath` defined this way in the command line:

```
-rpath @executable_path/../Frameworks
```

That should tell it to look in AppBundle/Contents/Frameworks/ for all frameworks.

[This](https://www.mikeash.com/pyblog/friday-qa-2009-11-06-linking-and-install-names.html)  is  another good article on the subject.

Comment: Thank you, it worked perfectly. Didn't know there're things like @executable_path before, the links are super helpful.